# Как сохранить xml файл на андроиде? - Программирование Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Всем привет.
Начинаю изучать программирование на андроид, поэтому понимаю, что вопрос нуба).
Хочу сохранить xml-файл, созданный моим приложением на телефон (тестирую на эмуляторе).
Прочитал аналогичные вопросы на этом форуме и других ресурсах.
Но у меня не получается сохранить это файл((
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это сделать?
Я взял за основу код, описанный на этом сайте (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-androidxml/index.html) и изменил его следующим образом:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.TextView;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;

import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private File xmlFile;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView     xmlResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xmlresult);

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

        Element rootElement = document.createElement("catalog");
        rootElement.setAttribute("journal", "Oracle Magazine");
        rootElement.setAttribute("publisher", "Oracle Publishing");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);

        Element articleElement = document.createElement("article");
        rootElement.appendChild(articleElement);

        Element editionElement = document.createElement("edition");
        articleElement.appendChild(editionElement);
        editionElement.
                appendChild(document.createTextNode("Sept-Oct 2005"));

        Element titleElement = document.createElement("title");
        articleElement.appendChild(titleElement);
        titleElement.appendChild(document
                .createTextNode("Creating Search Pages"));

        Element authorElement = document.createElement("author");
        articleElement.appendChild(authorElement);
        authorElement.
                appendChild(document.createTextNode("Steve Muench"));

        articleElement = document.createElement("article");
        rootElement.appendChild(articleElement);

        editionElement = document.createElement("edition");
        articleElement.appendChild(editionElement);
        editionElement.appendChild(document
                .createTextNode("November - December 2010"));

        titleElement = document.createElement("title");
        articleElement.appendChild(titleElement);
        titleElement.appendChild(document
                .createTextNode("Agile Enterprise Architecture"));

        authorElement = document.createElement("author");
        articleElement.appendChild(authorElement);
        authorElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bob Rhubart"));

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        Properties outFormat = new Properties();
        outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
        outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperties(outFormat);
        DOMSource domSource =
                new DOMSource(document.getDocumentElement());
        //OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
        xmlFile = new File(docsFolder.getAbsolutePath(), "file.xml");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult (xmlFile);
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        //String xmlString = output.toString();
        //xmlResult.setText(xmlString);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
    }

}
```

}

Но файл не сохраняется.
Подскажите, где ошибка?
Спасибо

Comment: Во-первых запомните, что при отладке блоки `catch` у Вас не должны быть пустыми - `e.printStackTrace();` очень поможет узнать какая именно ошибка помешала осуществиться Вашим планам. Здесь скорее всего Вы не получили разрешение `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Забыл указать, что в манифесте есть строчка:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> Но файл не сохранятеся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны действовать так.

1) Нужно получить разрешение на запись на внешнее хранилище. Для этого нужно прописать разрешение в AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2) Если это android MarshMallow или выше то права нужно запросить программно. Можно почитать об этом [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)
3) Что бы записать файл нужно создать для него папку

```
 File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
        docsFolder.mkdirs();
```

4) Далее нужно создать файл

```
xmlFile.createNewFile();
```

Код будет выглядеть вот так

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private File xmlFile;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

            Element rootElement = document.createElement("catalog");
            rootElement.setAttribute("journal", "Oracle Magazine");
            rootElement.setAttribute("publisher", "Oracle Publishing");
            document.appendChild(rootElement);

            Element articleElement = document.createElement("article");
            rootElement.appendChild(articleElement);

            Element editionElement = document.createElement("edition");
            articleElement.appendChild(editionElement);
            editionElement.
                    appendChild(document.createTextNode("Sept-Oct 2005"));

            Element titleElement = document.createElement("title");
            articleElement.appendChild(titleElement);
            titleElement.appendChild(document
                    .createTextNode("Creating Search Pages"));

            Element authorElement = document.createElement("author");
            articleElement.appendChild(authorElement);
            authorElement.
                    appendChild(document.createTextNode("Steve Muench"));

            articleElement = document.createElement("article");
            rootElement.appendChild(articleElement);

            editionElement = document.createElement("edition");
            articleElement.appendChild(editionElement);
            editionElement.appendChild(document
                    .createTextNode("November - December 2010"));

            titleElement = document.createElement("title");
            articleElement.appendChild(titleElement);
            titleElement.appendChild(document
                    .createTextNode("Agile Enterprise Architecture"));

            authorElement = document.createElement("author");
            articleElement.appendChild(authorElement);
            authorElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bob Rhubart"));

            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
            Properties outFormat = new Properties();
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.setOutputProperties(outFormat);
            DOMSource domSource =
                    new DOMSource(document.getDocumentElement());
            //OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


            File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
            docsFolder.mkdirs();
            xmlFile = new File(docsFolder.getAbsolutePath(), "file.xml");

            xmlFile.createNewFile();
            boolean qwe = xmlFile.exists();

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xmlFile);
            transformer.transform(domSource, result);
            //String xmlString = output.toString();
            //xmlResult.setText(xmlString);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)